# Oracle CASE next business day

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to calculate next business day in Oracle query. So on Monday - Thursday it should be `sysdate+1`, on Friday it should be `sysdate+3`, on Saturday it should be `sysdate+2` and on Sunday it should be `sysdate+1`.

I want to do it dynamically, rather than have lots of where statements covering the different days.

```
where order_date = CASE WHEN (1 + TRUNC (SYSDATE) - TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'IW')) < 5 
  THEN TRUNC (SYSDATE) + 1 
  ELSE TRUNC (SYSDATE + 4), 'IW')  
END
```

I found this from the answer [Next business day (Monday - Friday) in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46093349/next-business-day-monday-friday-in-oracle) but it seems error in query and I can't work it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `to_char(sysdate, 'fmday')` which returns the string name of the day:

```
where order_date =  
  case
    when to_char(sysdate, 'fmday', 'nls_date_language=AMERICAN') = 'friday' then trunc(sysdate) + 3
    when to_char(sysdate, 'fmday', 'nls_date_language=AMERICAN') = 'saturday' then trunc(sysdate) + 2
    else trunc(sysdate) + 1
  end
```

and better:

```
where order_date = 
  trunc(sysdate) + case
    when to_char(sysdate, 'fmday', 'nls_date_language=AMERICAN') = 'friday' then 3
    when to_char(sysdate, 'fmday', 'nls_date_language=AMERICAN') = 'saturday' then 2
    else 1
  end
```

Comment: Is it possible to simplify that further, no? There only seems to be the 2 cases in the answer I linked too, but 3 in yours. I am trying to work out why

Comment: There are 3 cases: Friday + 3 days, Saturday + 2 days and all the others + 1 day.

Comment: I highly recommend using NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE in the `to_char`function. Otherwise the result depends on the client NLS_LANG setting, which may not result into english day names. E.g. `TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'DAY', 'nls_date_language=AMERICAN')`

Answer (score 0):

to have the results from the statement, use below statement.

```
where order_date = 
(Select 
CASE WHEN (1 + TRUNC (SYSDATE) - TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'IW')) < 5 
  THEN TRUNC (SYSDATE) + 1 
  ELSE TRUNC ((SYSDATE + 4), 'IW')  
END from dual);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
WHERE order_date = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
                   + CASE TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'IW')
                     WHEN 4 THEN 3 -- Add 3 days on Friday
                     WHEN 5 THEN 2 -- Add 2 days on Saturday
                            ELSE 1 -- Add 1 day on all other days of the week
                     END
```